# Type resolution and method access error in JUnit test

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am writing unit tests with JUnit in my Java project, but I am encountering some errors. Here are the details of the errors I am facing:

```
Description: Type "Test" cannot be resolved
Resource: HelloWorldTest.java
Path: /HelloWorld/src/com/openclassrooms
Line: 9
Error Type: Java Problem

Description: Method "fail(String)" is undefined for type HelloWorldTest
Resource: HelloWorldTest.java
Path: /HelloWorld/src/com/openclassrooms
Line: 11
Error Type: Java Problem

Description: Type "org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions" is not accessible
Resource: HelloWorldTest.java
Path: /HelloWorld/src/com/openclassrooms
Line: 3
Error Type: Java Problem

Description: Type "org.junit.jupiter.api.Test" is not accessible
Resource: HelloWorldTest.java
Path: /HelloWorld/src/com/openclassrooms
Line: 5
Error Type: Java Problem
```

I do not understand why these errors are occurring and how to resolve them. I have imported the necessary dependencies in my project, including the JUnit libraries. I have also checked the paths and file names, but the errors persist.

Can you help me understand and resolve these errors? Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Code of the HelloWorldTest.java file:

```
package com.openclassrooms;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions; // Error here
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test; // Error here

public class HelloWorldTest {
    
    @Test
    public void testHelloWorld() {
        Assertions.fail("Intentional failure"); // Error here
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file, delete it (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_) or [in `module-info.java` add the required `requires ...;` statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules).